# What PCIe slots lanes do I have and do they overlap or conflict when installing PCIe SSD Card into slots on motherboard?

Tags: motherboard, pci-express, expansion-cards, pci-x

What PCIe slots lanes do I have and do they overlap or conflict when installing PCIe SSD Card into slots on motherboard?

Dell Motherboard Model and more references.

Dell Vostro 3902 - Motherboard: CN - 0T1D10

What kinda of PCIe / PCI slots do I have and what limitations would they have?

Speccy Details:

```
Manufacturer    Dell Inc.
Model   0T1D10 (CPU 1)
Version A01
Chipset Vendor  Intel
Chipset Model   Haswell
Chipset Revision    06
Southbridge Vendor  Intel
Southbridge Model   H81
Southbridge Revision    C2
System Temperature  28 °C
    BIOS
        Brand   Dell Inc.
        Version A06
        Date    8/19/2014
    Voltage
        CPU CORE    1.716 V
        MEMORY CONTROLLER   1.488 V
        +3.3V   2.040 V
        +5V 3.447 V
        -5V -11.904 V
        +5V HIGH THRESHOLD  2.782 V
        CMOS BATTERY    1.620 V
    PCI Data
            Slot PCI-E
                Slot Type   PCI-E
                Slot Usage  In Use
                Data lanes  x16
                Slot Designation    PCIEX16
                Characteristics 3.3V, Shared, PME
                Slot Number 0
            Slot PCI-E
                Slot Type   PCI-E
                Slot Usage  In Use
                Data lanes  x1
                Slot Designation    PCIEX1
                Characteristics 3.3V, Shared, PME
                Slot Number 1
            Slot PCI-E
                Slot Type   PCI-E
                Slot Usage  In Use
                Data lanes  x1
                Slot Designation    PCIEX1
                Characteristics 3.3V, Shared, PME
                Slot Number 2
            Slot PCI-E
                Slot Type   PCI-E
                Slot Usage  In Use
                Data lanes  x1
                Slot Designation    PCIEX1
                Characteristics 3.3V, Shared, PME
                Slot Number 3
```

[image: Click to Zoom details]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I’m a little out of touch with changes in PCIe X related  changes and implementations on the Motherboard.

I may have vaguely read about some conflict or overlaps of PCIe slots on motherboards between diff ones based on number of lanes etc that they use.

I’m wondering if both PCIe Ex 1 slots show on 2  sides of the PCIe Ex 16 are equivalent if I am to use 2 them?

- The PCIe 16 and one of the other PCIe 1 x ones.

**Insights**?

Ps: Images being uploaded from phone shortly.

Motherboard + Slots

[image: mobo slots]

PCIe 3 card for SSD

[image: PCIe 3 SSD]

PCIe Card for extra USB 3 + SATA port dock

[image: inateck]

Comment: Whether slots share bandwidth or cause other slots to switch down to lower numbers of lanes is something only your motherboard manual can say. We cannot guess from a picture. Typically if you have a slot you should be able to use it.

Comment: @Mokubai It’s a dell machine and what if I shared the model & try to post the mother board model number. Let me try to find some of the above.

Comment: @AlexS You don't really have to bother anyway since the board has only one x16 slot, which means even if it has to share lanes with the x1 slots, there will still be more than 4 lanes that it can uses.

Comment: @AlexS Btw in the case of Haswell, the CPU should at least provides 16 3.0 lanes, which is used by the primary x16 slot, while the motherboard / chipset will provide a few more 2.0 lanes that are shared by other "narrower" slots and the secondary x16 slot, if any. FYR: [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haswell_(microarchitecture)#Desktop_processors) and [this](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/75016/intel-h81-chipset/specifications.html)

Comment: @TomYan - Is it possible to add/ extend the one x16 slot into multiple?

Comment: @AlexS Probably not on such an old board (especially not one of these "brand name" vendor oem boards, as they are mostly lame and cheap). PCIe bifurcation requires UEFI firmware and maybe even CPU support, AFAIK.